# OneNote intercepts pen cursor before AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

Palm rejection is garbage on my laptop, so I disabled the HID touchscreen to make it so that only pen input registers. So, I used AHK to make a script that will scroll around the page after the user presses `ALT`, and disables scrolling upon the second `ALT` press.

It works great, except that in OneNote (the Win 10 app), pen cursor input is hijacked by OneNote. For example, if I make a `ToolTip, %xPos% %yPos%`, then it won't update while my pen cursor is hovering anywhere above the OneNote window. Anywhere outside this works fine.

How can I make AHK steal pen cursor input before OneNote can get it?

```
isTabletMode := 1
penScrollActive := 0

#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2   ; Allows a second instance to modify penScrollActive while PenScroll is looping.
$Alt::
    ; Check if PC is in tablet mode.
    ;   1 --> Tablet, 0 --> Desktop
    RegRead, isTabletMode, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell,TabletMode
    if(isTabletMode) {
        if(penScrollActive) {
            penScrollActive := 0  ; We are already scrolling, so turn it off.
        }
        else {
            penScrollActive := 1 ; We are not scrolling yet, so turn on pen scrolling.
        }
    GoSub PenScroll
    }
    else    ; If we aren't in tablet mode, then Alt should just send Alt
        Send, {Alt}
    return

PenScroll:
    loop {    ; For some reason, while() logic wasn't working, so this is a workaround. Breaks upon the conditional at bottom.
        MouseGetPos, mouseX, mouseY
        ToolTip, %mouseX% %mouseY%   ; For debugging: Output what cursor pos registers as.  (This isn't working in OneNote when using the pen input as a cursor (eg. hover) ).
        Sleep, 20
        MouseGetPos, mouseX_new, mouseY_new
        if (mouseX_new - mouseX > 0)        ; Horizontal scrolling
            Send, {WheelLeft}
        else if (mouseX_new - mouseX < 0)
            Send, {WheelRight}
        if (mouseY_new - mouseY > 0)        ; Vertical scrolling
            Send, {WheelUp}
        else if (mouseY_new - mouseY < 0)
            Send, {WheelDown}
        if (penScrollActive = 0)            ; Conditional to break out
            break
    }
    return

; To Reload the script: Win+`
#`::Reload
Return

#If penScrollActive
LButton::Return
```

Comment: Have you tried running your script as an admin?

Comment: Yes. It seems like the pen hovering, while it has a cursor, isn't the actual cursor. Because if I put my cursor at, say `(100,100)`, then hover the pen over another part of the screen, and then move my actual mouse again, the cursor re-appears at `(100,100)`. So I need a way to get the *pen* coordinates rather than the mouse coordinates, as they are different.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could maybe try is my [AutoHotInterception](https://github.com/evilC/AutoHotInterception) library for AHK. You install a custom device driver, then you can hook into input events at the driver level, below the OS.
It supports "Absolute" (Graphics-tablet-like) mouse input
You want the "Subscription Mode" endpoints